# PHP, MYSQL, select results based on all values from 3 dropdowns being true

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 drop-down lists and one select box, Country (dropdown), region (dropdown), gender (select box x 2).

my database looks like this (i have cut down the number of values)

```
| id | england | usa | west | north | male | female | name | age |
|  1 |    1    |  0  |  1   |   0   |   0  |   1    | John |  33 |
|  2 |    0    |  1  |  0   |   1   |   0  |   1    | John |  56 |
```

Apart from the ID and additional values each value i need to query will  be 1 or 0 (true or false)

the result i need is if someone selects england, west, male it brings back every row which has those values as true (their is extra information on these rows i need to display)

I just need some pointers on how to achive this i was thinking of using a lookup table but am struggling to use lookup table with multiple values, or do i just use php and set each value to its correct row name and do a query like that

Comment: That is pretty bad database design. Did You really need use this database schema?

Comment: i am up for suggestions, i have been supplied the database like the above

Comment: Create two tables: countries (id|name), genders(id|name) and link them to main table via foreign key

Answer (score 2):

First of all

I suspect you are mixing the schema (column names) and the values up in your database.

Your table should be more like

```
|id | country |region | gender |
--------------------------------
| 1 | usa     | north | male   |
| 1 | england | south | female |
```

Think about what properties the thing has that you're trying to model.
You already kind of have this in your drop-downs. Each drop-down has a list of possible values for that property.

While you're at it, you should probably go further and split your data into more tables.

```
countries
|id | name   | other | columns | about | countries | eg. iso_code|
------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1 | USA    | ....  |  .....  | ..... | ......    | us          |
| 2 | England| ....  |  .....  | ..... | ......    | uk          |

regions
| id | name      |
------------------
| 1  | north     |
| 2  | south     |
| 3  | east      |
| 4  | west      |
| 5  | south-west|
| .. | ....


users
|id | name | country_id |region_id | gender |
---------------------------------------------
| 1 | John | 1          | 1        | m      |
| 2 | Mary | 2          | 4        | f      |
```

You would then have to come up with ways of converting your data form the old system into the new.

First take over some of the data from the original table

```
 INSERT INTO new_users (id,name) SELECT id, name FROM old_users;
```

This will insert the names with the same IDs as the original table in the new table.

Create the data for the lookup tables (country and region in this case)

```
 INSERT INTO countries (name,iso_code) VALUES
    ('USA','us'),
    ('United Kingdom','uk'),
    ....
```

Then update your fields

```
 UPDATE new_users 
     FROM new_users INNER JOIN old_users ON old_users.id = new_users.id 
 SET new_users.country_id = 1 WHERE old_users.usa =1;

 UPDATE new_users 
     FROM new_users INNER JOIN old_users ON old_users.id = new_users.id 
 SET new_users.country_id = 2 WHERE old_users.england =1;
 ...
 etc...

 UPDATE new_users 
     FROM new_users INNER JOIN old_users ON old_users.id = new_users.id 
 SET new_users.region_id = 1 WHERE old_users.north =1;

 UPDATE new_users 
     FROM new_users INNER JOIN old_users ON old_users.id = new_users.id 
 SET new_users.region_id = 2 WHERE old_users.west =1;
 ...
```

Once you have that sorted...

Your drop-downs should be something like.. (you can generate the dropdowns automatically from your lookup tables (e.g. *countries*) by listing all the values with their names)
When you add new countries to the table, they will automatically appear in the drop-down from now on.

```
<?php  
....
while ($resultrow = $result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $resultrow['id'] ?>">
      <?php echo $resultrow['name']; ?></option>
}
```

You should end up with something like the following in your html output.

```
<select>
  <option value="1">USA</option>
  <option value="2">UK</option>
</select>
```

Then your search query should look something like this:

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM table 
         WHERE `country_id`= '$country_id'
           AND `region_id`= '$region_id'
           AND `gender`= '$gender'";
```

Comment: thank you for this, sorry i did not explain it very well, i have amended my answer above to show 2 rows, and some additional data

Comment: I understand your schema, what I am saying is that it is bad and you should redesign it. Read about database [normalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)